# One-liner to Count the Number of Methods I've defined in a Ruby Class?

Tags: ruby

What's the simplest way I can list the methods defined at each level in the tree?

```
Admin < User < ActiveRecord::Base < ...
```

...and be able to take those methods and say which we defined in which module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Admin.ancestors.each{|a| puts "For #{a} #{a.instance_methods(false)}"}
```